# Pandas groupby and sum operators

Tags: python, pandas

I wish to generate a new column which contains the sum of another column, depend on its `id`.

I can use `groupby` to restrict per `id` and then `sum` to total `Volume` the values from the `Volume` column.

`results['sum'] = results.groupby('id')['Volume'].sum()`

However, this returns `NaN` for all fields.

I thought there must be an issue with the `Volume` column format and thus tried a different operator. The following works fine:

`results['min_volume'] = rsults.groupby('id')['Volume'].transform('min')`

What else could cause a `NaN` output?

Comment: Cannot answer without seeing raw data, code to create the df and your code that demonstrates this

Comment: Perhaps your column has a NaN or non-float data type?  Nan + anything = nan

Comment: You are trying to assign an aggregated result to the original dataframe. Number of rows in the original dataframe and the number of rows in the returning series are different (series is grouped so it has fewer rows).. You actually found the solution - you need `transform` if you want to modify the original dataframe.

Comment: Thanks @ayhan. `transform('sum')` was the winner

Comment: @AdamHughes I don't think [nan, anything].sum() is nan: `pd.Series([1, np.NaN, 3]).sum()` returns 4.0

Comment: Ah sorry, thank you.